My chrome Extension buttons stops working is it because of Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated
This is error I am getting. but I have read somewhere that this is normal in development phase. I am junior developer so may be thats why I am getting the right solution. can anyone please guide me??

Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated.

content.js
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
if (isDisplayable) {
    // Save data or perform necessary actions before sending the message
    // Example: localStorage.setItem('unsavedData', yourData);

    // Attempt to send message to background script (best-effort)
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'beforeunload' }, function(response) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });

    const confirmationMessage = 'You have unsaved data. Are you sure you want to leave?';
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
}});

What is the solution for this?

Welcome to SO! Please make your question clear - do not put the question in the title - do not show images but text - show the code that you wrote How to ask

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
